Please help identify this component 1.6 x 2.9 mm 6 pin SMD, SOT26 package
I am having no luck identifying this SMD. I tried all my usual reference tricks but still no success.
This is the whole board. The red arrow bottom center points to the component in question.

I am trying to fault find a power problem on this ATE brand ABS (automotive antilock brake) control module.
According to diodes.com the orientation is the dot at the bottom left making it
a WPs 96 asymmetrical marked package.
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Package-Files/SOT26.pdf

To those who are curious....
This started with a "lost communication with ABS" error code using a OBD2 scanner on a 2010 Mazdaspeed 3. I purchased the car with a blown engine (conrod through block) and rebuilt it, this error may be new or may have been already present with prior owner....unknown..
After confirming solid power to all three 12V supplies and good Ground I "gained access" to the board (wood chisel worked great) and began tracing.
Red marked traces on the board are CAN BUS high & low and show signal all the way to the IC.
System power is supplied by the pin marked with the red dot. high current for the pump motor and control solenoids is supplied by the bottom two pins in the connector side of the picture.
I cannot find good supply voltage to the large IC's and the eprom (bottom right of the big IC) this is surely a LDO regulator problem.
I am pretty sure the suspect component is my ~MYSTERY~ 6 pin.
might just Feed the known power side of the eprom with 3.3 Volts and see if things begin to talk, a problem exists though with low resistance on that power trace so I may remove my mystery component if it presents itself as a hot point.

Given the nearby components, it seems part of the input overvoltage or polarity protection, perhaps a comparator or reference, perhaps logic gate, dual transistor, etc. Can you test other nodes in the circuit, locate supplies, see if there is a problem with power flow in the circuit?

It's probably an Infineon BCR192U dual digital PNP transistor.

I can't find a picture of this specific part, but here is a picture of the BCR523U that shows a similar marking style:

(source: mikrocontroller.net)
